# how can i write a cross-platform python program that handles keyboard events and color terminal input/output

Tags: python, eval, curses

I'm trying to write a game that is capable of displaying colorized text in the console window and manipulating it based on certain key combinations.

The idea is to make a game that helps teach the user vim with the focus on optimizing python development. The idea is to have a rising wall of text, containing pythonic soup that's not properly arranged. As each line reaches the top of the screen, it is interpreted. The user must scroll around the text with the cursor and play with it using certain vim command mode combinations (but no insert mode) in an attempt to manipulate the text in such a way that it arranges it into the proper python commands and syntax to achieve certain objectives, while racing against time as the text rises.

I think python would be the easiest language to code this in, since I can just `eval` each line that needs to be interpreted, though I am open to using another language with embedded python if that would be easier.

As far as my options in python go, here is what I have considered:

- Curses.

  This is the most intuitive to me.. I'm sure I could create exactly what I'm looking for, with the one caveat being that it would only run in a Linux environment.

  Ideally, I'd like for Windows users to be able to run the game too, and while this would be possible for Windows users who have properly set up Linux emulators, this is a bit more overhead than I would like. If there is an easy way for a Windows user to run the program that wouldn't require them to learn too much about Linux and could be easily installed, this would be my ideal approach, but the various approaches (VMWare, cygwin, and colinux) don't seem to satisfy this criterion.
- Develop this for Linux AND Windows.

  This seems like it would be more work than necessary, although once I've developed it using Curses, maybe porting it to something similar in Windows wouldn't be too hard.
- Pygame.

  From what I understand, this is cross-platform and is equipped to do everything I need it to. However, I would have to do a lot more work to have my program handle text and the user input, text scrolling, etc. I'm not planning on using any of the graphical capabilities of Pygame, so this also seems like it would be too much work/borderline impossible.
- Another language?

  Perhaps I could embed Python for no other reason than to invoke the "eval" command, while using another language that this would better-tailored to these objectives. My background is strongest in C and C++, and I'm a very rusty novice Java user. I'm acquainted with Javascript too and have been looking for an opportunity to learn more. Javascript would be a piece of cake in the way of portability, but from what I understand, developing this kind of game in JS/HTML5 would be a nightmare. Maybe something else that I'm less familiar with would be better?

Comment: Have you checked [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html) out?

Comment: @PedroRomano: Urwid is POSIX only.

Comment: [`wcurses`](http://code.google.com/p/wcurses/) is a Windows port of the python [`curses` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html), should be a good starting point.

Comment: Other than that, I fear your question is not constructive (see the [FAQ#dontask]); you are basically asking for recommendations instead of asking for help with concrete problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: apparently it can be [made to run](http://www.mail-archive.com/urwid@lists.excess.org/msg00017.html) on Windows natively by using `wcurses`. But it's probably not fully functional (it mentions _display only_).

Comment: The sources in the [github repo](https://github.com/adamv/wcurses) of wcurses seems to be just for Windows, right?

Comment: @erikb85: correct; you use `curses` on POSIX platforms, `wcurses` *instead* on Windows.

Comment: you could write it in emacs: it has modes that emulate vi to some degree e.g., [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) (so it is possible to achieve vim-like behavior in it), emacs is cross-platform, there is [pymacs](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html) to interface with python, it is possible to write games that run in emacs e.g., [tetris](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TetrisMode)

Comment: It seems like there's a fine line between asking for recommendations and asking for guidance in approaching a problem with certain requirements. I'm asking for a concrete way my requirements can be met. The only one I could think of is Pygame, but that seems like it would be overkill. I have read the faq, and reasoned this question would be compliant because I'm looking for answers that would provide a working approach (there may be more than one, but this doesn't mean that every approach is valid) to a real problem I'm facing that I outlined, and which has not been answered yet

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you know this had actually crossed my mind. I am not at all familiar with emacs, but it seems like if I was this might even be the simplest approach. At the same time, I don't know that someone with emacs installed would be interested in running a game in it to learn python development optimization with vim :D

Comment: @PedroRomano: It mentions two *other* curses ports in that post, `cursesw` and `pdcurses`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you're right! I apologise for the incorrection (I think I'm a bit dyslexic today and the `w` just jumped from one end to the other). Like I said, I am not sure if it is viable. I just think _Urwid_ is much nicer to work with than plain _curses_. A shame about the _POSIX only-ness_... :(

Comment: google suggests pygcurse (pygame-based) e.g., [textris](https://github.com/asweigart/pygcurse/blob/master/demo_textris.py). It might help to estimate the amount of work for the pygame route